# Is there any separate events are available for update and create?

Tags: magento

```
    <!-- The code of the event we want to observe -->
    <catalog_product_save_after>
        <!-- Defining an observer for this event -->
        <observers>
            <!-- Unique idetifier should be in lowercase letter -->
            <xx_xxxx>
                <!-- The model to be instantiated -->
                <class>xx_xxxx/observer</class>
                <!-- The method of the class to be called -->
                <method>productAddUpdate</method>
                <!-- The type of class to instantiate -->
                <type>singleton</type>
            </xx_xxxx >
        </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_after>
```

*This is my code and this event is triggering for both product update and create is there any separate events available for update and create separately?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no separate events but you can check the difference in your observer. Your method `productAddUpdate` can receive a parameter of type `Varien_Event_Observer` that holds the product being saved. You can check if the product is new or being updated like this.

```
public function productAddUpdate($observer){
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if ($product->isObjectNew()) { 
        // the product is being added
    }
    else {
        //the product is being updated
    }
}
```

The method `isObjectNew` is available for any entity type in the save method and events triggered by this method.